# Huge memory usage by Redis when used as a Celery broker because of reply pidboxes

Tags: python, redis, celery, django-celery

We are running celery 3.1.8 with Redis as the broker backend. 
Our config is pretty simple and we don't care about results, for this we set

```
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
```

However we noticed that our redis broker instance takes a huge amount of memory (~3GB) while the actual number of queues and messages in them is quite small at any given moment.
After examining the RDB file, we noticed there are a few huge lists:

```
database,type,key,size_in_bytes,encoding,num_elements,len_largest_element
0,list,"ed2d26b5-b8fb-3478-ace7-6714e8a7b4ed.reply.celery.pidbox",70733024,linkedlist,4,17696745
0,list,"e3eda502-27eb-348d-a86e-1d78fc31b165.reply.celery.pidbox",35350876,linkedlist,2,17686857
0,list,"6421b8c1-bbc0-3a59-a7ee-f26450552a60.reply.celery.pidbox",35443327,linkedlist,2,17762611
0,list,"8439dcd0-921e-3922-8504-9057b6c9834a.reply.celery.pidbox",106088780,linkedlist,6,17696745
0,list,"85c667c8-63b6-338f-b00a-e1f2cd4da143.reply.celery.pidbox",17762845,linkedlist,1,17762611
0,list,"05d0c0f2-9530-37f3-a9cb-189fc237303c.reply.celery.pidbox",106088769,linkedlist,6,17696743
0,list,"d3f200fd-c81e-3d6d-acf3-d0e9021e7e5c.reply.celery.pidbox",35431615,linkedlist,2,17762611
0,list,"7b4291c7-b916-3806-910b-c250c9a7fece.reply.celery.pidbox",88401866,linkedlist,5,17696745
0,list,"0c8b64c1-7efe-3070-b2e3-980f395b84e8.reply.celery.pidbox",123752294,linkedlist,7,17696743
0,list,"e5cf288b-8ced-3f6c-891e-34e2d302c89c.reply.celery.pidbox",70711492,linkedlist,4,17691717
0,list,"a9cafe29-204d-3d97-9b7b-322a847d0789.reply.celery.pidbox",53121613,linkedlist,3,17762611
0,list,"1c1f90ca-1fe1-35e4-a144-3a97177a674b.reply.celery.pidbox",35431683,linkedlist,2,17762611
```

These lists contain a few json items each containing a huge Body.

Any pointers to why these reply pidboxes are present even though we set celery to ignore result?
Are they needed by celery if we have no interest in the results of the tasks?
We would like to get rid of these, since they are turning an instance that should take ~10mb of memory to take ~3gb of memory.

Any help would be great, let me know if you need more info on the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the setting you are looking for that should get rid of those pidbox messages is `CELERY_SEND_EVENTS`. It is enabled by default, for tools like celerymon. However, for me setting `CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False` doesn't change anything. You might give it a shot though, maybe it works for you.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#celery-send-events

> CELERY_SEND_EVENTS
>
> Send events so the worker can be monitored by tools like celerymon.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out and see if it solves. For now we noticed these lists are added slowly, so we have a task that cleans them. The weird thing is we don't use celerymon or anything similar, these events are being added by something in celery itself.

Comment: CELERY_SEND_EVENTS is (now?) turned off by default. I'm having the exact same issue as the OP by the way

Answer (score 0):

To completely disable pidbox usage logic on the worker, you can unset CELERY_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL

https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-enable-remote-control

Please do note that this means you will lose certain run time change abilities. You will not be able to ask for which queues the worker consumes from, it's active tasks, adding queues, etc.

As such part of the feature set of flower will then likewise be limited.

It may be possible that earlier versions of the library would send these stats/info on the pidbox under other circumstances.